# If Statement: If MYSQL Value = Null?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

Hi, I have a query that pulls user photos.

There's one function that if the user is logged in they can view large photos, the other function is if the user is logged out they cant view large photos.

I am now trying to add another function to say: if the user doesn't have any photos and their are no entries in the table 'ptb_photos' then echo image templates.

At the moment with the 'if($photos == null)' I'm getting the users with photos images displaying but the blank template images are also showing up in multiple lines and these blank templates should only show up on those users without photos.

Can someone let me know where I'm going wrong?

```
<?php
$get_photos_set = get_photos();
while ($photos = mysql_fetch_array($get_photos_set)) {
    if (logged_in()) {
        echo "<li><a href=\"data/photos/{$photos['user_id']}/{$photos['file_name']}\" rel=\"prettyPhoto[pp_gal]\"><img src=\"data/photos/{$photos['user_id']}/thumb_{$photos['file_name']}\" alt=\"{$profile[2]}'s Photos\"  /></a></li>";
    }

    if (!logged_in()) {
        echo "<li><a href=\"login.php\"><img src=\"data/photos/{$photos['user_id']}/thumb_{$photos['file_name']}\" alt=\"{$profile[2]}'s Photos\"  /></a></li>";
    }

    if($photos = null) {
        echo "<li><a href=\"login.php\"><img src=\"assets/img/icons/usertemplate.png\" /></a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href=\"login.php\"><img src=\"assets/img/icons/usertemplate.png\" /></a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href=\"login.php\"><img src=\"assets/img/icons/usertemplate.png\" /></a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href=\"login.php\"><img src=\"assets/img/icons/usertemplate.png\" /></a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href=\"login.php\"><img src=\"assets/img/icons/usertemplate.png\" /></a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href=\"login.php\"><img src=\"assets/img/icons/usertemplate.png\" /></a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href=\"login.php\"><img src=\"assets/img/icons/usertemplate.png\" /></a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href=\"login.php\"><img src=\"assets/img/icons/usertemplate.png\" /></a></li>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What unexpected behavior are you seeing? What is the expected behavior you want to see? Where is the function definition of `get_photos()`?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if($photos = null)
```

to

```
 if($photos == null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if($photos = null)
```

You may want to try

```
if(mysql_num_rows($get_photo_set) == 0) {
...
}
```